# Unable to get javax.mail to be found by package

Tags: java, microsoft-openjdk

I've written a program that uses log4j and it set to use the SMTPAppender at Error/Fatal level

```
   <SMTP name="ErrorMail" subject="iMCtoOVO ERROR" to="addresses@company.com" from="server@client.com" smtpHost="clientgateway.client.com" smtpPort="25" bufferSize="100">
    <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </SMTP>
```

It was working fine with standard Oracle Java, but since switching to OpenJDK, due to licensing, installed with the Microsoft installer, I have not been able to get it to work.

```
2022-09-15 14:52:15,568 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apacche.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender for element SMTP: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
```

Under Oracle Java, I had only been able to get this to work by putting the javax.mail.jar in the "ext" folder.  I can find no such location now on this system.  I have tried putting the path in the manifest Class-Path, removing Class-Path from the Manifest and specifying the location by java -cp (see below in case I've lost my ever loving mind) in various formats (e.g. quoted, \ and / absolute and relative path, wild card etc), I have rebuilt the runnable JAR with all necessary packages built in (Eclipse IDE) and I am out of ideas.

```
java -cp G:\iMCAlarmParse\lib\javax.mail.jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/g:/iMCAlarmParse/conf/log4j2-dev.xml -Dimctoovo.WorkPath=g:/imcAlarmParse/ -jar iMCAlarmParse-dev.jar
```

I'm sure it's something amazingly dumb I'm missing in the stack trace but I'm at my wits end.

For reference:
openjdk 17.0.4.1 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40354 (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40354 (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your build system? Could be that you only have an issue in building your jar-file?

Comment: @cyberbrain sorry, I didn't specify.  I'm running Eclipse IDE

Comment: hmmm. you are not using ant, maven, gradle, or any other build system that you could also trigger from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are adding an outdated dependency, try

> javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2

instead. You could use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api to get the binary, search for different versions, or try to switch to its successor jakarta.mail-api instead. (But this requires updates to the software as the package names changed.)